# OS command stop at regular interval with python

Tags: python, vlc

I wanted to stop and restart a function in python at regular interval[let's say 1 hour], were function contains os.system();#needed command

Inside os.system, an cvlc program is trying to capture stream and saving in local disk. I need to stop at each one hour , and will be providing new file name for next start.

Sample code will be appreciated...!

Comment: Your try will be much appreciated .. :)

Comment: I've tried and it's not happening. Do I need to use subprocess library in python?

Comment: Just Post what your tried and will help you..

Comment: I've imported threading in python & I created two functions. One contains the os.system line and another function which is as follows 'code' threading.Timer(6.0,save()).start() 'code'

Comment: @jOSe edit it in your answer, write a code snippet. people here wont write entire code but they will only suggest you the improvements.

Comment: `code  threading.Timer(6.0,save()).start() ` Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Please a minimal example or the full code to your post! The one-liner is not helpful.

Comment: I've got the solution, apart from using 'threading' I've imported 'subprocess'

Comment: For production on Linux I would consider making your python program into a service so it could be stopped and started from a bash service script. Then a cron job could be created for it that would stop and start it every hour.  Some information about how to make an executable into a Linux service is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336075/linux-process-into-a-service.