# Run a script having multiple commands as service at boot time

Tags: bash

What is the best way to start a script at boot as a service. I need the following commands to run.

```
    #!/bin/bash
  VBoxManage startvm "cuckoo-window" --type gui &
  cd  /opt/cuckoo/utils/
    sudo python api.py --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8090 &
  cd /opt/cuckoo/web/
    sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8008 &
    sudo python /opt/cuckoo/cuckoo.py &
```

Comment: You're expected to provide which operating system you're using.

Comment: you can look at this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336075/linux-process-into-a-service to create service, and this link - http://askubuntu.com/questions/9382/how-can-i-configure-a-service-to-run-at-startup to run the service at boot

Comment: answer depends on OS.

Comment: @sjsam  I am using ubuntu server 14.04