# Raspberry Pi python script in Sl state

Tags: python

i got a python script to collect data from a few connected sensors. This script runs in background from starting the PI. The script is working fine but irregular it fells in 'Sl' state. If i restart the PI it works again for a few days, but then it happens again.

Is there a way to monitor the state of the script (kill it and start it again if this happens) or any idea why this happen?

Comment: You can write another program that checks if the script is in currently running or not. If it isn't, just restart it. You can setup a cron job for running this program at appropriate regular intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options (somewhat related):

1. Run your script as per normal, but have another script (`bash` works good) that checks for the state of your script.  If it's stalled, `kill` it, and restart.  This second script can be called from a regular `cron` job.
2. Change your python script into a linux service (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336075/linux-process-into-a-service) for an example), and either monitor this service with a second script (similar to *1*), OR, do a `service restart` at regular intervals with a `cron` job.